# Error: 'ansi_hyperlink_types' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cli'

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, testthat

I am exploring unit testing in R based on [this](https://stirlingcodingclub.github.io/code_testing/testing_notes.html#).

So I installed the `testthat` package and wrote a simple function and a test as mentioned in the above link. Here is the code

```
library(testthat)

f_to_c <- function(F_temp){
  C_temp <- (F_temp - 32) * 5/9
  return(C_temp)
}

#test
test_that(desc = "Fahrenheit to Celsius", code = {
  
  temp <- f_to_c(50)
  expect_that( object = temp, condition = equals(10) )
  expect_that( object = is.numeric(temp), condition = equals(TRUE) )
})
```

Here is what I am getting

```
Error: 'ansi_hyperlink_types' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cli'
```

What could be the reason for this error and how to solve this? Or, is there a different way to run tests in R? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the error with this code. I get the output `Test passed `

Answer (score 5):

I have had this problem recently. I believe it was something that was corrupt or broken with the `CLI` package. It would not let me update the package so removing it and reinstalling it seemed to do the trick.
Running:

```
remove.packages("cli")
install.packages("cli")
```

Fixed it for me.

I would also recommend as a course of action updating R and RStudio as well as other packages.